# an error with dplyr:summarize - Error in eval

Tags: r

I made a dataframe and tried to manipulate it using `group_by` and `summarize`

```
FEL = c('color','price','NA','color','manual','money')
TA = c('galaxy','Iphone','galaxy','Iphone','NA','samsang')
POS = c(1,0,2,1,2,1)
NEG = c(0,1,1,1,0,0)
dat = data.frame(POS,NEG,TA,FEL)

dat %>% group_by(FEL) %>% summarize(POLAR = POS-NEG)
```

However, I got this error below.

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : expecting a single value
```

I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: `"expecting a single value"`: `POS-NEG` gives a vector, not a single summary value like a mean/max/min etc.

Comment: Do you just want: `dat %>% mutate(POLAR = POS-NEG)` ?

Comment: You cannot `summarise` elements that return the same length.  Suppose you take the difference and then the `mean` or `max` or `sum` of it, then that works i.e. `dat %>% group_by(FEL) %>% summarize(POLAR _SUM= sum(POS-NEG))`

Comment: Its not clear what you want...but you can try something like `dat %>% mutate (POLAR = POS-NEG) %>% group_by(FEL) %>% summarize(POLAR_SUM = sum(POLAR))`

Comment: Oh.... What I want is actually to use `mutate`. I didn't know there is a function like it. Thx, though.

Comment: I suspect this is the first time I've seen somebody use `%>%` and `summarize` and *not* know about `mutate`, arguably one of the pioneer and notable functions for which the package is known. (`dplyr` has many other useful functions, don't be afraid to keep scouring SO for other `dplyr`-related questions to see the types of tricks accepted answers demonstrate.)